# Use calc function in CSS in JS in React component

Tags: css, reactjs, styles, calc

I am working on one react component in which I need to use calc function in styles

```
const styles = {
  spotImg:{
    maxWidth:"100%",
    maxHeight:"100%"
  },
  spotCont:{
    width: /*here want to use calc with screen width*/
  }
}
```

I want to use screen width with calc function in the above style code in react js component.

Comment: What about `vw`?

Comment: i want to some calc width screen width ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
const styles = {
  spotImg:{
    maxWidth:"100%",
    maxHeight:"100%"
  },
  spotCont:{
    width: "calc(100vw)", 
     fallbacks:["-moz-calc(100vw)", 
     "-webkit-calc(100vw)",
     "-o-calc(100vw)
     ]
  }
}
```

Put the calc function in double quotations, and then you can use the CSS's `vw` to access screen width. Ie, `100vw` provides you with the entire screen width. `100vw - 250px` provides you with 250px less than the screen width, for example.

EDIT: Added fallbacks based on OP's comment about browser not accepting calc function.

Comment: when I put like this width: "calc(100vw-250px)" it not accept by browser

Comment: I'm guessing your browser isn't allowing calc by default, so you need fallbacks. I edited my answer to include fallbacks

Comment: Watch that often calc() requires spaces around the operator to work: "calc(100vw - 250px)"